# Compare mysql tables to see if a record is available for each entry

Tags: mysql, left-join

I have two mysql tables. jobsreqtraining and coursescompleted.

jobsreqtraining has two columns, job and training.

coursescompleted has two columns, course and person.

snapshot below:

jobsreqtraining

[image: jobsreqtraining]

coursescompleted

[image: coursescompleted]

What I need to do is say if Bryan Habana does job Crane Operator, has he completed the 'MHE Drivers License' Course?

so my query would have two variables, Job and Person. so if I chose Bryan Habana and Crane Operator my desired output would be

---

**Training**              
              **Completed Course?**

Crane Operator               No

---

I beleive I have to use a left outer join to acheive this but battling to get the course required for the job to be shown even if the person has not completed the training?

```
select 
  n.course, 
  c.person
from (select 
  training as course 
  from jobsreqtraining where Job='crane operator'
) as n 
left outer join coursescompleted c 
  on n.course=c.course 
where c.person='bryan habana'
```

Help appreciated as always,
Thanks,

Comment: how are the tables related with each other?

Comment: There is no relation currently.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are  `coursescompleted.course` and `jobsreqtraining.training` joined together? If yes, you could use this:

```
SELECT jobsreqtraining.job as Training,
  IF(EXISTS(SELECT * FROM coursescompleted
            WHERE coursescompleted.person='bryan habana'
              AND jobsreqtraining.training = coursescompleted.course), "Yes", "No)
FROM jobsreqtraining
WHERE jobsreqtraining.job = 'crane operator'
```

Answer (score 2):

```
SELECT 
  n.person,
  j.job AS job,
  j.training AS Training,
  CASE WHEN c.person IS NULL THEN 'No' ELSE 'Yes' END AS `Completed Course?`
FROM jobsreqtraining j 
  CROSS JOIN (select distinct person from coursescompleted) n
  LEFT JOIN coursescompleted c
    ON j.training = c.course AND n.person = c.person
WHERE 
  n.person = 'Bryan Habana'
  AND j.job = 'Crane Operator'
```

[live demo at sqlfiddle.com](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34858/19)

Note that you can vary the `WHERE` clause to select different sets of information for different people and/or different jobs.  Even works for *multiple* people and/or jobs.

[Here is an example with the where clause omitted completely](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/34858/20). It shows all jobs for all people, with a yes/no indication for each.

Answer (score 1):

```
select 'creane operator' `job`,
CASE WHEN (select count(*) from coursescompleted where person='bryan habana'
and course=(select training from jobsreqtraining where job='crane operator')) > 0 
then   'Yes'  else 'No' END `Completed Course`
```